# Insert NA if a value does not exist when create a new dataframe from an existing one

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and I try to keep some values of it into a loop using a code like:

```
dfnew<- rbind(dfnew, data.frame(var1new= df$var1,
                                var2new = df$var2))
```

Sometimes the var1 or var2 doesn't exist into the df and the problem is that there is a error as the df has not the same column length as the dfnew and the loop stops to execute.

Is there any simple way to insert NA if the value doesn't exist? Aimining not to check previously the values with many lines of code.
Something like this

```
dfnew<- rbind(dfnew, data.frame(var1new= df$var1 || NA,
                                var2new = df$var2|| NA))
```

Comment: You are likely doing this stuff very sub-optimally. `rbind` inside a loop is very seldom a good idea. You'd better initialize `var1new` and `var2new` before the loop, fill the values inside and only after the loop you should create your resulting `data.frame`. Post the full story and a reproducible example to receive valuable help.

Comment: I agree with @nicola. You should share your full code and give us a minimal data example to work with. Otherwise you just solve one problem and find a new one! For reference [use this description to create sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use if statement:

```
dfnew<- rbind(dfnew, data.frame(var1new= ifelse(is.null(df$var1),NA,df$var1) ,
                            var2new = ifelse(is.null(df$var2),NA,df$var2)))
```